# Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography Deserialize Error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, serialization, deserialization

Our production application recently started getting the elusive "There is an error in XML document (1, 6110)."  Up until a few days ago everything was working as expected.  I don't have access to the server logs to see if any unexpected updates were performed, but I can't think of a reason why it has been working fine and now doesn't.  Just for reference, this is happening on load of a Data set from a web service.  The culprit column datatype is Geography and I can confirm the correct version of Microsoft.SqlServer.Types is present on Client and Server sides.  "is not allowed here." is what I can't figure out?!?!

Below is the complete error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was caught
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=There is an error in XML document (1, 6110).
  Source=System.Xml
  StackTrace:
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
       at DataFutures.DatabaseRoutines.DFIWebTier.DFIWebTier.Web_ReturnLoadedDataSet(String TableName_String, Boolean UseStoredProcedure_Boolean, String SQLCommandOrStoredProcedureName_String, String ParameterName_String, String SelectValue_String, String ParameterName2_String, String SelectValue2_String, SQLParameter_Class[] SQLParameter_SQLParameter_Class, String ConnectionString_String, String Database_String) in C:\DevApps\TeamServer\Generic Routines\DLLs\DatabaseRoutines\Web References\DFIWebTier\Reference.vb:line 240
       at DataFutures.DatabaseRoutines.DF_DataBaseClass.Database_Return_LoadedDataSet(String DataTable_String, Boolean UseStoredProcedure_Boolean, String SQLCommandOrStoredProcedureName_String, String ParameterName_String, String SelectValue_String, String ParameterName2_String, String SelectValue2_String, String ConnectionString_String, SqlTransaction SQL_SqlTransaction, List`1 SQLParameter_SQLParameter_Class, String Database_String) in C:\DevApps\TeamServer\Generic Routines\DLLs\DatabaseRoutines\Classes\DF_DatabaseClass.vb:line 1442
       at DataFutures.DatabaseRoutines.DF_DataBaseClass.get_ExecuteReturnLoadedDataSet() in C:\DevApps\TeamServer\Generic Routines\DLLs\DatabaseRoutines\Classes\DF_DatabaseClass.vb:line 736
       at DataFutures.Maintenance_Health.FacilityIC_Form.LoadTabPage_GeneralTab() in C:\DevApps\TeamServer\CareScope\Modules\Maintenance\Facility\FacilityIC_Form.vb:line 3905
  InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=Type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography, Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' is not allowed here. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132227 for more information.
       Source=System.Data
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.TypeLimiter.EnsureTypeIsAllowed(Type type, TypeLimiter capturedLimiter)
            at System.Data.DataColumn.UpdateColumnType(Type type, StorageType typeCode)
            at System.Data.DataColumn.set_DataType(Type value)
            at System.Data.XSDSchema.SetProperties(Object instance, XmlAttribute[] attrs)
            at System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleElementColumn(XmlSchemaElement elem, DataTable table, Boolean isBase)
            at System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleParticle(XmlSchemaParticle pt, DataTable table, ArrayList tableChildren, Boolean isBase)
            at System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleComplexType(XmlSchemaComplexType ct, DataTable table, ArrayList tableChildren, Boolean isNillable)
            at System.Data.XSDSchema.InstantiateTable(XmlSchemaElement node, XmlSchemaComplexType typeNode, Boolean isRef)
            at System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleTable(XmlSchemaElement node)
            at System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleDataSet(XmlSchemaElement node, Boolean isNewDataSet)
            at System.Data.XSDSchema.LoadSchema(XmlSchemaSet schemaSet, DataSet ds)
            at System.Data.DataSet.ReadXSDSchema(XmlReader reader, Boolean denyResolving)
            at System.Data.DataSet.ReadXml(XmlReader reader, XmlReadMode mode, Boolean denyResolving)
            at System.Data.DataSet.ReadXmlSerializable(XmlReader reader)
            at System.Data.DataSet.System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
            at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ReadSerializable(IXmlSerializable serializable, Boolean wrappedAny)
            at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ReadSerializable(IXmlSerializable serializable)
            at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderDFIWebTier.Read6_Item()
            at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer7.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
            at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
       InnerException:
```

Comment: The link behind the error (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132227) does not mention `SqlGeography` as a supported type for deserialization scenarios. The question is not "why it is not working now", the question is "why was it working before" (perhaps no geography input in previous data)?

Comment: I agree with "why was it working before".  This functionality has been in production for 3 years and there is a lot of geo data.  This past Friday, is when it showed up.  I have tracked it down to the client side.  I am guessing a recent Windows 10 update is the culprit.  So I plan on going through the updates for July to see if I can determine which one it is and check for a hot fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is right there in the link.  You have to opt-in for serializing types other than the basic ones.  You probably have this configured for a previous version of the Spatial types, but when they were updated on the server, the configuration didn't get updated on the client.

Here's an example:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Types;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SqlClientTest
{

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {



            var constr = "server=localhost;database=master;integrated security=true;";

            using (var con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                con.Open();

                Type[] extraAllowedTypes = new Type[]
                {
                    typeof(SqlGeography)
                };

                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("System.Data.DataSetDefaultAllowedTypes", extraAllowedTypes);

                var sel = new SqlCommand("select geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(-122.360 47.656, -122.343 47.656 )', 4326) shape", con);
                var da = new SqlDataAdapter(sel);

                var ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                ds.WriteXml(ms, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);

                ms.Position = 0;
                using (var f = File.OpenWrite("out.xml"))
                {
                    ms.CopyTo(f);
                }
                ms.Position = 0;

                var ds2 = new DataSet();
                ds2.ReadXml(ms);

            }


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, David!  I will give this a try within my database class and see if that takes care of it.

Comment: That took care of it.  Thanks!!  For reference, the following windows update was the culprit for me.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4565633/kb4565633-cumulative-update-for-net-framework